# jQuery swfobject AS3 ExternalInterface not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, swfobject, externalinterface

As you can tell by the title, I am having some trouble with AS3 ExternalInterface and jQuery / swfobject.

ActionScript :

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    ExternalInterface.call('init');
    ExternalInterface.addCallback('testFunc', returnFunc)
}

function returnFunc():void {
    ExternalInterface.call('alertFunc');
}
```

jQuery:

```
function init() {
    alert('init');
    $('#swf_object').testFunc();
}

function alertFunc() {
    alert('finished');
}
```

Obviously that implies the object has the id 'swf_object'

I have also tried getting the object by the following:

```
document.getElementById('swf_object')
document.getElementById('swf_object')[0]
$('#swf_object')[0]
```

To no avail.

It's giving the first alert ('init') but then not doing the last one. I'm completely baffled and hope someone can point out my mistakes! (there's bound to be a massively obvious one somewhere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling out to the JavaScript `init()` which calls the Flash `testFunc()` *before you're made testFunc available* (which happens only *after* the call out to `init()` completes).

To fix this, simply swap the two lines to this:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback('testFunc', returnFunc);    // Needs to be available before it's used
ExternalInterface.call('init');
```

As for getting the Flash object in JavaScript, you can do it directly with `document.getElementById('swf_object')`, but it's possible using jQuery too:

```
var swf = $('#swf_object').get(0);    // Get the actual object without the jQuery wrapper
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple like that! I'm pretty new to ActionScript but that was blindingly obvious! I was expecting ActionScript to keep reading through the code (like JavaScript) but it turns out it waits on functions (like PHP). I remember having the opposite problem when I was learning JavaScript, expecting it to wait for functions to be carried out!

Comment: @Andrew: AS3 and JS (in a browser) are actually quite similar in that respect -- both are hosted in single-threaded environments, so make heavy use of asynchronous functions. But, whenever you call a function, it's a synchronous operation (in both (and all I can think of) languages). The trick to reconciling these two concepts is that a function that starts an asynchronous operation *will run synchronoulsy* -- it's simply not doing the whole operation at once (just the first bit).